# SQL monitoring in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

In our application we do deployment through Jenkins pipeline but few of the resources (don't know them by their names) do have DB credentials for higher environments (e.g. SIT or UAT). So sometimes, in case of any small break in the application they quickly fix that issue by manually logging in into the DB.

Is there any way in Oracle where I can monitor those activities (e.g. which machine logged in OR who executed any DDL or DML or any PL/SQL block)? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like exactly what AUDIT was *designed* for.  Start in the official docs: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10575/tdpsg_auditing.htm#TDPSG50000